# Python access property from parent class

Tags: python

I am following [this tutorial](https://edube.org/learn/pe-2/queue-aka-fifo-part-2-1) on Python Institute.

I have three classes as shown below. The parent class Queue has put and get functions. The *get* function raises a QueueError if the queue is empty. The child class SuperQueue has to add the isempty function which returns true if the queue is empty. My first approach was to call the parent class *get* function inside a *try* block and return its returned value if present. Otherwise, catch the error in the except block and return true.

My second approach shown in code was to create a *get* function for the child class. In that function, I grab the returned value in a variable. If the returned value is not empty, I put it back into the queue and return it to the caller. In this way, when I call the *get* function inside the *isempty* function, the queue is intact.

The problem here is that the driver program, after entering some items into queue, calls the *isempty* function and if the queue is not empty, it calls the *get* function to print the items. So the *get* function is called twice and my code does not print the entered items in the order they were entered.

How can I implement the *isempty* function?

```
class QueueError:
    pass
class Queue:
   def __init__(self):
       self.queue=[]

   def put(self,elem):
         self.queue.insert(0,elem)
   def get(self):
     if len(self.queue) > 0:
        elem = self.queue[-1]
        del self.queue[-1]
        return elem
    else:
        raise QueueError
 class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
      Queue.__init__(self)
    def get(self):

       try:
        v= Queue.get(self)
        return v
       except:
        print('exception')

     def isempty(self):
        v=self.get()
        if v:
           self.put(v)
           return False
       return True


 que = SuperQueue()
 que.put(1)
 que.put('dog')
 que.put(False)
 for i in range(4):
   if not que.isempty():
      print(que.get())
   else:
      print("Queue empty")
 # I cannot get queue items in order. I get the second Item first and cannot get the third
 (False)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `def isempty(self): return len(self.queue)==0`? Why would you call `self.get()` (which fetches from the back of the queue) only to `self.put(v)` which inserts at the front of the queue?

Comment: It can be a bit confusing to call the child class 'Super'-something. In many languages, the `super` operator/method is used to access the parent-typed part of the current object.

Comment: Aside: you should use `super().__init__()` to call the parent class's `__init__()` method, rather than using the parent class's name explicitly.

Comment: really, there should simply be no `__init__` method in the child class

Comment: thanks i don't know why they ask me to do this exercise this way. but any way i need to fix  adding to the rear rather than to front to keep queue intact before calling get function again thanks quamrana

Comment: actually there is no way of doing this unless the child class has access to queue in parent class.

Comment: Opening the link: *"403. We’re sorry but you don’t have access to this feature. Please make sure you access it from an authorized source only. "*

Comment: Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get 100% of what you need to implement because I find the [link](https://edube.org/learn/pe-2/queue-aka-fifo-part-2-1) you served is not accessible from my environment.  In general, it is little bit weird why do you need to call `get()` method (which affects the .queue list itself) in implementing `isempty()` method while you can just check the length of the list as **quamrana** commented above.

But I respect there is some context you were asked to do in this way, and would love to add some comment which help to clarify what possibly makes you confused.

First of all, below is the code I think might work in the way closest to what you intended:

```py
class QueueError(Exception): # ...(1)
    pass

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
   
    def put(self, elem):
        self.queue.insert(0, elem)

    def get(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            elem = self.queue[-1]
            del self.queue[-1]
            return elem
        else:
            raise QueueError

class SuperQueue(Queue):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() #...(2.1)

    def get(self):
        try:
            v = super().get() #...(2.2)
            return v
        except:  
            print('Queue is now empty')
  
    def isempty(self):
        v = self.get()
        if v is not None: # ...(3.1)
           self.queue.append(v) # ...(4)
           return False
        return True


que = SuperQueue()
que.put(1)
que.put('dog')
que.put(False) # ...(3.2)
for i in range(4):
    if not que.isempty(): # ...(3.3)
        print(que.get())
```

The output of executing above code is as follows.  The order does not mix up and it can print the last item of the queue also.

```bash
1
dog
False
Queue is now empty
```

There are four different points which might help you to be clear about what confuses you in your implementation, all of which are denoted as numbered comments in my suggested code above:

##### (1) QueueError needs to inherit from `Exception` class

This is minor one. I added this just because your code raised error at this part in my environment.

##### (2) Use of super keyword to call parent class

This one is same with what **Barmar** commented.  At **2.1**, you need to call `super().__init__()` for your SuperQueue instance to prepare its member list `.queue`.  `Queue().__init__()` does not work in this case.

##### (3) `isempty()` method should be able to handle boolean properly

Let's see your code again here:

```py
def isempty(self):
    v=self.get()
    if v: # <--
        self.put(v)                
        return False
    return True
```

The arrow-marked line makes problem when it comes to the boolean element `False` you inserted as the last element.

In implementing `isempty()`, You might have intended "if anything could be passed to `v`, return `False`". But in above case, list element `False` screws up your if condition.  The boolean element 'False' **EXISTS** in the queue but it cannot pass your if condition as it is literally **FALSE** as boolean.

This is the reason why you couldn't see the last item `False` displayed executing the code you implemented.  I just modified the if condition to check whether return from `get()` is None or not to handle this.

##### (4) Removed element is not inserted again to right position

Your `get()` method checks whether there is any element at the end of the list and delete it if it does.  From your `isempty()` method, however, to restore the deleted element you called `put()` method which inserts element at the head of the list.  This makes the order of items screwed up in calling `isempty()`.  This could be solved by using `append`, which adds item at the end of the list.  But this is not a good implementation in the sense that it reveals the structure of `Queue` class (that it is using list to store items).

Comment: thank you very much for explaining it so clearly. My problem was that I could not access the queue list and did not know why. Now I see using super in constructor will solve problem right?

Comment: Using super constructor clearly is a point you start from.  But it does not automatically help you to see the last element from queue (`False`) printed.  After changing `Queue`s to `super`s you would get to know that.  You may also need to handle other stuffs I explained finally.